# li-On charger Reverse polarity protection

Tags: voltage

I have   built the attached Li-On Battery charger based on MCP 73831 chip and it works well. However I would like to add a reverse polarity protection to it since I've burned 2 chips while putting the battery to be charged the wrong way. 
Is there a reliable way to do this and sorry for my poor english language.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Schottky diode in series! You do however need to move the voltage feedback point to behind the diode which in many cases is not possible.

Comment: Use a polarized connector so that this does not continue to happen. Also, I connect batteries to power supplies all the time. I don't think I have ever done it backwards. It seems a bit surprising that you have done it twice.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen electronic polarity protection on lithium batteries. Normally a polarized connector is used so that it is not possible to connect the battery with reverse polarity. Barring that, I would think that red/black color coding would be enough to prevent reverse polarity connections.

But if you REALLY want a circuit solution, here it is.

[image: battery-reverse-polarity-protection]

Q1 should be a PMOS FET with low Rds(on) at 2.7V. One possibility is alpha and omega p/n AO3401A. Q2 can be a 2n3904 or any typical logic BJT.

Note that this circuit will prevent a totally dead battery from charging. The battery must be at least 0.6V or so to turn on Q2.

Comment: Q2 could also be an NMOS FET such as a BSS138, but then the turn-on voltage would be even higher.

Comment: "Note that this circuit will prevent a totally dead battery from charging" - Good. If a Lithium-ion cell reads less than 2.5V then it is permanently damaged and not safe to recharge.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I'll put the mofdification suggested by mkeith and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, yeah but a protected cell may present itself as "dead" even though the internal cell voltage is above 2.5V.

Comment: Li-Ion cells are NOT damaged by going below 2.5v, though they may loose some capacity.  But they should be trickle-charged back up to 2.5v before applying a regular charge current.  This is to prevent lithium plating on the anode.  That is also a danger when charging any Li-Ion cell while cold.  Cells should also be monitored for heat buildup when charging at any rate over 0.5A.

Answer (score 0):

The "ideal" solution would be adding an ideal diode circuit. You could also use mechanical reverse polarity protection by using connectors that can't be reversed.